# How to create all possible punctuations within a group in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, data-manipulation

My original data is as follows:
`id      co     year
1385    1447    1993
1426    1447    2001
*
38      1487    1967
1644    1487    2008
1703    1487    2009
*
1578    1678    1979
150     1678    2002
**
1069    1690    1989
1070    1690    1993
1652    1690    1996
1596    1690    1997
**
1542    1704    1977
842     1704    2003`

I'd like to create an output like: 
`id      co     year
1385    1447    1993
1426    1447    2001
*
38      1487    1967
1644    1487    2008
1644    1487    2008
1703    1487    2009
*
1578    1678    1979
150     1678    2002
**
1069    1690    1989
1070    1690    1993
1070    1690    1993
1652    1690    1996
1652    1690    1996
1596    1690    1997
**
1542    1704    1977
842     1704    2003`

The scenario is:
when I have more than 3 COs I need to **create extra observations for COs** which are not first or last in the year sequence.

I don't evan know how to start it. Could anyone help me? I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the by operator and then the first and last options. Do an extra output if it's not first and last co. The dataset needs to be sorted by co and year.

```
proc sort data=have;
 by co year;
run;

data want;
 set have;
 by co;
 if not first.co and not last.co then output;
 output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the group by and to get the counts per co and in the same expression you can also get the minimum year and maximum year which can be excluded from the inserts.

here is the solution for you

The below is just for creating the test table and not part of the solution

```
create table test
(
  id int, co int, year int
)

truncate table test
insert into test values (1385,1447,1993)
insert into test values (1426,    1447,    2001)
insert into test values (38  ,    1487,    1967)
insert into test values (1644,    1487,    2008)
insert into test values (1703,    1487,    2009)
insert into test values (1578,    1678,    1979)
insert into test values (150 ,    1678,    2002)
insert into test values (1069,    1690,    1989)
insert into test values (1070,    1690,    1993)
insert into test values (1652,    1690,    1996)
insert into test values (1596,    1690,    1997)
insert into test values (1542,    1704,    1977)
insert into test values (842 ,    1704,    2003)

--select 'before',* from test
```

here is the solution

```
;with C as 
(
  select min([year]) minimum_year, max([year]) maximum_year, count(1) as Counts, co from test group by co 
)
insert into test
select T.* 
from C 
JOIN test T
ON C.co = T.co
and c.counts >=3
and T.[year] <> C.minimum_year
and T.[year] <> C.maximum_year

select 'after',* from test order by co,id
```

you can also check out this fiddle for the execution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e12de/9

Comment: This wouldn't work in SAS, which doesn't allow `with`.